# What happens to files in docker container when host is shut down ungracefully?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, shutdown

Let's say I have a docker container running some application, that will sometimes write some data to a file in a folder, that is not mapped to the host. Given the host is shut down in an ungraceful way (like power cables pulled out), what happens to the files that are stored inside the container but not mapped to the host? Will they persist? Does it get removed?

Comment: If you want to maintain any sort of state, then you should be doing that on a mounted volume.

Comment: @SiHa  Although i agree with what u say, but your reply does not seem to answer his question. He is not asking what is the recommended way of doing thing.  He is more of asking what is going to happen.

Comment: @NickWills. Here's a thing; If I was attempting to answer the question, I'd have posted an answer - the clue is in the title. As it happens, the question had already been answered, so I just left some advice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The files are deleted. Containers are ephemeral in nature. When the container starts it creates a new writable layer on top of the image, and whatever changes you make are on that layer. If you are not storing/mapping that layer data to some persistent location, then once the container or Docker daemon or host machine restarts all the data is lost.

Comment: As metnioned, the datastorage of spinning container is bound to the container, once the container is killed , not spinning anymore, from principle the whole content of the container is lost (in kubernetes / openshift the containers are running in the pods, mechanism is the same), if you would like to have some persistent storage, then you have to mount some volue, and you can reconnect it to the newly spinned container afterwards to persist the data

Answer (score 7):

If such power disconnects or crash happens to your system the container goes into stop state and whatever data you saved before power disconnect will stay inside the container file system as long as it is not terminated. You can as access your data again by re-starting that container.

But yes as Dashrath Mundkar and xxxvodnikxxx said in their answers in case of cluster environment of containers, it gets killed and new-one is started in its place so you will loose all your data if it is not stored in any persistent mounted storage.